# directory browsing enabled - page doesn't get redirected

Tags: asp.net

I'm encountering this weird issue, I can't go to this url http://localhost:63026/videos/upload.aspx/?tp=1. This url get's changed to http://localhost:63026/videos/upload/?tp=1 and I get shown the directory list of the upload folder instead. 
I was getting "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" which I resolved by enabling directory browsing by including this line `<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />` in my web.config file.

I moved the files of my other project to the current project because I was having some issues with that one. In that project I don't get this issue of not being directed to the url and I don't need to enable direcotry browsing. What is directory browsing and why do we need it? How can I go to the correct url?

This is what I see when I try to go to the url:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i think....

you said that you moved  files from one project to another  but when u recopied all files i think you missed bin directory in which you probably missed App_global.asax.dll and App_global.asax.compiled files And Because of these files were missing in  IIS ...giving you this error....and not to forget diable directory browsing in iis.

Comment: no this is not my default page. The page is located inside the upload folder inside the video folder which is in the root directory.

Comment: I don't have any files that exist with that name in the bin folder.